# Flutter - Constructor Confusion

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

On the home page of the app, the user clicks on the account they want to view and the balance from the data model page for that specific account is displayed (see screenshots).  I thought I knew what to do but nothing is working. I have it working for other sections of the app, however I can't get it to work here.  How can I achieve this?  Here is the code:

On the OwenTab page, i want to replace the "Text($20.00)" with the actual balance from the data model page.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OwenTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const OwenTab({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text(
          '\$20.00',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text(
              'Available to spend',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded, size: 30),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where the OwenTab() is imported.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../pages/eloise_tab.dart';
import '../../pages/henry_tab.dart';
import '../../pages/owen_tab.dart';

class MoneyTabBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int tabIndex;

  const MoneyTabBar({
    super.key,
    required this.tabIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: tabIndex,
      length: 3, // 3 tabs
      child: Scaffold(
        // TabBar Background Color
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,

        body: Column(
          children: const [
            TabBar(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80),
              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              tabs: [
                // "Owen" Tab
                Tab(
                  text: 'Owen',
                ),

                // "Eloise" Tab
                Tab(
                  text: 'Eloise',
                ),

                // "Henry" Tab
                Tab(
                  text: 'Henry',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 25),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  // "Owen" Tab Content
                  OwenTab(),

                  // "Eloise" Tab Content
                  EloiseTab(),

                  // "Henry" Tab Content
                  HenryTab(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the data models code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/child_tile.dart';
import '../models/home_tile.dart';

class GoHenryData extends ChangeNotifier {
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  LISTS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  final List<HomeTile> _homeTiles = [
    HomeTile(
      iconImagePath: 'lib/assets/images/price-sticker.png',
      title: 'New in GoHenry',
      subTitle: 'Your app has new features!',
      boxColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    HomeTile(
        iconImagePath: 'lib/assets/images/money.png',
        title: 'Set up mission payments',
        subTitle: 'Reward your kids for learning',
        boxColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
    HomeTile(
        iconImagePath: 'lib/assets/images/well-done.png',
        title: 'School\'s out?',
        subTitle: 'Transfer money, say well done',
        boxColor: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    HomeTile(
        iconImagePath: 'lib/assets/images/chat.png',
        title: 'Claim you bonus',
        subTitle: '\$50 for every friend referral',
        boxColor: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  ];

  final List<ChildTile> _childTiles = [
    ChildTile(
      avatarImagePath: const AssetImage('lib/assets/images/owen.jpg'),
      childName: 'Owen',
      balance: '\$20.00',
      totalBalance: '\$22.00',
      savingsBalance: '\$0.00',
      bottomName: 'Owen',
    ),
    ChildTile(
      avatarImagePath: const AssetImage('lib/assets/images/eloise.jpg'),
      childName: 'Eloise',
      balance: '\$22.00',
      totalBalance: '\$40.00',
      savingsBalance: '\$0.00',
      bottomName: 'Eloise',
    ),
    ChildTile(
      avatarImagePath: const AssetImage('lib/assets/images/henry.jpg'),
      childName: 'Henry',
      balance: '\$15.00',
      totalBalance: '\$20.00',
      savingsBalance: '\$0.00',
      bottomName: 'Henry',
    )
  ];
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  GETTERS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  List<HomeTile> get homeTiles => _homeTiles;

  List<ChildTile> get childTiles => _childTiles;

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  ADDERS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  REMOVERS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Here is the HomePage(), just in case:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gohenry_clone/components/tiles/child_tile.dart';
import 'package:gohenry_clone/pages/money_page.dart';
import 'package:gohenry_clone/pages/savings_page.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../components/tiles/home_tiles.dart';
import '../data/gohenry_data.dart';
import '../models/child_tile.dart';
import '../models/home_tile.dart';
import 'cards_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GoHenryData>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
        // AppBar
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 255,
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            color: Colors.red.shade400,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // Header
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Your parent balance',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Balance
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '\$40.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 36,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Text
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Next allowance in 2 days \$10.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // "Add Money" Button
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => {},
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            width: 190,
                            child: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Add money',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 12.0,
                        ),

                        // "Transfer" Button
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => {},
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            width: 190,
                            child: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Transfer',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Home Banner Tiles
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: value.homeTiles.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    HomeTile individualHomeTile = value.homeTiles[index];
                    return Padding(
                      padding: index == value.homeTiles.length - 1
                          ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0)
                          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: HomeTiles(
                        homeTiles: individualHomeTile,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Child's Main Tiles
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: value.childTiles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  ChildTile individualChildTile = value.childTiles[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    child: ChildTiles(
                      childTiles: individualChildTile,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => MoneyPage(
                              tabIndex:
                                  index, // Goes to corresponding child's account tab
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      onPress: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const CardsPage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      onPressTwo: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const SavingsPage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the MoneyPage(), just in case:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../components/widgets/money_tab_bar.dart';

class MoneyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tabIndex;
  const MoneyPage({super.key, required this.tabIndex});

  @override
  State<MoneyPage> createState() => _CardsPageState();
}

class _CardsPageState extends State<MoneyPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.pie_chart_outline, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text(
          'Money',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
      body: MoneyTabBar(tabIndex: widget.tabIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your data is in the GoHenryData widget, which is a ChangeNotifier. As you presumably know from getting this far, the purpose of this widget is to provide application state to it's descendants.
I'm also going to assume that you have correctly provided your changenotifier to your application, as seen [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).
The next step is to access that data with the Consumer widget. The data you are looking for would then be `goHenryData.childTiles[0].totalBalance`.

However, creating an individual widget for each of the hardcoded children is a poor design. Rather than creating an OwenTab, an EloiseTab, and a HenryTab, create a ChildTab that takes a ChildTile as a parameter in it's constructor and can be re-used for all 3. You can then dynamically create tabs based on the list of ChildTiles in the state.

Assuming childTiles is the list of ChildTiles in the app's state, you could then generate the tabs as follows

```
childTabHeaders = childTiles.map((e) => Tab(text: e.childName)));
childTabs = childTiles.map((e) => ChildTab(childTile: e));
```

These can then be used to build the MoneyTabBar widget, which could now support any number of children. Additionally, you don't need to know anything about the number/names of the children as you write the code, allowing you to do something like load the data from a database. This would be necessary for any practical use of an app like this.